# How to set the Product Default Price while increasing or decreasing quantity in cart and checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: product, cart, onepage-checkout

I don't want to increase or decrease product prices based on quantity. Please help me with how we can achieve this. Suppose Bag product price is 10 and the quantity added is 20, the price should be 10 only on the cart and checkout page.

In short, price should remain the same while increment and decrement of quantity

Like
1qty = 10$
2qty = 10$
3qty = 10$

Instead of
1qty = 10$
2qty = 20$
3qty = 30$

Thanks

Comment: could you please be more specific? you started with 'I don't want to increase or decrease product price based on quantity', but from the title I understand the opposite. which is it?

Comment: @DianaBotean I don't want product price to increase when quantity is increased.Ignore title.Can you please give any idea.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you could us the 'Buy X Get Y Free' cart rules. have you tried to see if it's what you need?